# Is it possible to define an operator that accepts a parameter of a generic numerical type different than the base class?

Tags: c#, generics, casting, operator-overloading, .net-generic-math

I want my container to do element-wise arithmetic, but I can't figure out how to make an operator definition accept type parameters.

```
public static Stats<T> operator + (Stats<T> a, Stats<T2> b) 
    where T2 : System.Numerics.IAdditionOperators<T2,T,T>
```

I'm a python programmer trying to learn C# by exploring game development. My goal is to create a `Dictionary<string,INumberBase>` to hold the stats of a player that accepts keys from a limited set and supports arithmetic operations such as addition and multiplication to be performed element-wise by key. My current solution has been to define a class that contains a regular dictionary and define operator methods. I would also like it to support casting its dictionary to a different numerical type i.e. `Stats<byte>` to `Stats<ulong>` or to use overflow checking to increase the memory size dynamically.

Sorry if this is a dumb question. I don't have any experience with type declarations and interfaces since python takes care of all of that implicitly.

I tried to use operator methods but I don't know how to declare `T2` in the example above. I also tried to define casting methods but ran into the same problem, though I'm not sure I was doing that properly to begin with.

I could simply replace `T2` with `int` and every other numeric type, but that seems like a code smell. I could also define a `public multiply<T2>` method, but that also seems like a code smell when there's an  operator override syntax built into the language.

Edit:

My new solution is to subclass `Stats<ulong>` and `Stats<byte>` and define an `operator` on `Stats<byte>` that multiplication by `uint` gives a `Stats<ulong>` instance. Thanks everyone for all your input and helping me understand interfaces and dynamic types!

Comment: _" My goal is to create a `Dictionary<string, INumberBase>` "_ - first of all there is no non-generic version of `INumberBase`. Can you please show some [mre]?

Comment: `T` in this case cannot be changed dynamically once created. You can work on it *generically* so that if given a `Dictionary<string, T> where T : INumberBase<T>` and you don't know what `T` is then you can do addition etc. But you can't make such a constructed `Dictionary<string, byte>` into a `Dictionary<string, int>` it's just not compatible. Generics aren't simply dynamic types, they represent *placeholders* for types, and once used to create an object cannot be changed within that object.

Answer (score 1):

C# does not support generic operator overloading - see [this discussion](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/discussions/612), operator declarations does not allow syntax for declaring the generic type parameters - [spec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#1510-operators). So you need either to manipulate on the same types:

```cs
class Stats<T> where T : IAdditionOperators<T,T,T>
{
    public T Stat { get; set; }
    public static Stats<T> operator+(Stats<T> a, Stats<T> b) => new() { Stat = a.Stat + b.Stat };
}
```

Or declare custom methods:

```cs
class Stats<T> where T : IAdditionOperators<T,T,T>
{
    public T Stat { get; set; }

    public static Stats<T> operator+(Stats<T> a, Stats<T> b) => new() { Stat = a.Stat + b.Stat };

    public Stats<T> Plus<T2>(Stats<T2> s) where T2 : IAdditionOperators<T2, T, T>, IAdditionOperators<T2, T2, T2> =>
        new() { Stat = s.Stat + Stat  };
}
```

Also note that there is no non-generic `INumberBase` interface, so you can't do `Dictionary<string, INumberBase>`.